# XPATH - how to get inner text data littered with <br> tags?

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I have HTML text like this

```
<p>
This is some important data
<br>
Even this is data
<br>
this is useful too
</p>


<othertag>
 data
</othertag>
<moretag>
 data
</moretag>
```

I'm trying to query the following with XPATH

`//p//text() | //othertag//text() | //moretag//text()`

which gives me text which is broken at the point of each `<br>` tag

like this

```
('This is some important data','Even this is data','this is useful too','othetag text data','moretag text data')
```

I'd like it as a complete string,

```
('This is some important data Even this is data this is useful too')
```

because i'll be querying other elements using `|` Union XPATH operators and its very important this text content is properly divided

How can i do this?

If this is impossible,

can i atleast get the inner HTML of `<p>` somehow

So that i can **textually** store it as

```
This is some important data<br>Even this is data<br>this is useful too
```

I'm using `lxml.html` in `Python 2.7`

Comment: did you delete your previous questions?

Comment: @kjhugues: An HTML parser will parse those `<br>` tags just fine, and then you can use XPath expressions.  No cleanup necessary.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Based on your edit, maybe you can use the XPath `string()` function.  For example:

```
>>> doc.xpath('string(//p)')
'\n    This is some important data\n    \n    Even this is data\n    \n    this is useful too\n  '
```

---

(original answer follows)

If you're getting back the text you want in multiple pieces:

```
('This is some important data','Even this is data','this is useful too')
```

Why not just join those pieces?

```
>>> ' '.join(doc.xpath('//p/text()'))
['\n    This is some important data\n    ', '\n    Even this is data\n    ', '\n    this is useful too\n  ']
```

You can even get rid of the line breaks:

```
>>> ' '.join(x.strip() for x in doc.xpath('//p/text()'))
'This is some important data Even this is data this is useful too'
```

If you wanted the "inner html" of the `p` element, you could call `lxml.etree.tostring` on all of it's children:

```
>>> ''.join(etree.tostring(x) for x in doc.xpath('//p')[0].getchildren())
'<br/>\n    Even this is data\n    <br/>\n    this is useful too\n  '
```

NB: All of these examples assume:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = etree.parse(open('myfile.html'),
...    parser=etree.HTMLParser())
```

Comment: Not me, but i cannot use a `join` because like it says in the question, i'll be using a union operator. when this text is mixed in with other data, the format breaks.

Comment: Could you update your question with some example data and an xpath query against that data that demonstrates the problem you're trying to solve? That would make it easier to come up with an answer that works for you.

Comment: `doc.xpath('string(//p)')` only seems to get the text data of the first node, no more :(

Answer (score 2):

You can also expose your own functions in XPath:

```
import lxml.html, lxml.etree

raw_doc = '''
<p>
This is some important data
<br>
Even this is data
<br>
this is useful too
</p>
'''

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(raw_doc)
ns = lxml.etree.FunctionNamespace(None)

def cat(context, a):
    return [''.join(a)]
ns['cat'] = cat

print repr(doc.xpath('cat(//p/text())'))
```

which prints

```
'\nThis is some important data\n\nEven this is data\n\nthis is useful too\n'
```

You can perform the transformations however you like using this method.

Comment: cat() gives `lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Unregistered function`

Comment: Did you register it? (i.e. the `ns['cat'] = cat`) ?

Comment: right, got that fixed but i cannot do `cat(//p/text()) | //othertag/text()` gives `invalidtype Error`

Comment: @wolfgang: It works for me if I make it return a list type (see update).